# why do I get a blank tkinter window?

Tags: python, tkinter

so when i run this code and click the button:

```
from Tkinter import *
import thread
class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        print master

        def creatnew():

            admin=Tk()
            lab=Label(admin,text='Workes')
            lab.pack()
            admin.minsize(width=250, height=250)
            admin.maxsize(width=250, height=250)
            admin.configure(bg='light green')
            admin.mainloop()
        def other():
            la=Label(master,text='other')
            la.pack()
            bu=Button(master,text='clicks',command=lambda: thread.start_new_thread(creatnew,()))
            bu.pack()
        other()

Admin = Tk()

Admin.minsize(width=650, height=500)
Admin.maxsize(width=650, height=500)
app = App(Admin)
Admin.mainloop()
```

i get a second tkinter window but its a white blank screen that makes both programs not respond.
any ideas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use threads.  It's confusing the Tkinter mainloop.  For a second window create a `Toplevel` window.

Your code with minimal modifications:

```
from Tkinter import *
# import thread # not needed

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        print master

        def creatnew(): # recommend making this an instance method

            admin=Toplevel() # changed Tk to Toplevel
            lab=Label(admin,text='Workes')
            lab.pack()
            admin.minsize(width=250, height=250)
            admin.maxsize(width=250, height=250)
            admin.configure(bg='light green')
            # admin.mainloop() # only call mainloop once for the entire app!
        def other(): # you don't need define this as a function
            la=Label(master,text='other')
            la.pack()
            bu=Button(master,text='clicks',command=creatnew) # removed lambda+thread
            bu.pack()
        other() # won't need this if code is not placed in function

Admin = Tk()

Admin.minsize(width=650, height=500)
Admin.maxsize(width=650, height=500)
app = App(Admin)
Admin.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should only call `mainloop` once. You don't call it forveach toplevel, only for the app as a whole.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley:  Correct!  I initially noticed that, but forgot to fix it.  I tried to preserve as much of his code as possible.  Fixed now.